# Get events without start and end date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

In the [Microsoft Graph Calendar API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0) I can get all events with the request url:

`/me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}`

But I have to specify a start and end date. Is there a way to just get all events without specifying the dates?

Just leaving the dates out of the request gives me an error that it is missing those parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/calendarView` endpoint is designed to give you a rendered view of a calendar for a given date range. Without a date range, the API would have to render every event in the calendar, potentially going back decades. The computational cost of doing that could be excessively high, not to mention the negative impact it would have on performance at scale.

If you just want the raw underlying `event` objects, you can use the [`/events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint. This will give you paged results containing every event in that calendar. You will need to do some post-processing to render individual instances for repeating events based on the master event (i.e. events with `"eventType": "seriesMaster"`).

In general, I would recommend using `/calendarView` since it handles rendering the series instances for you. You can effectively imitate retrieving "everything" by passing it a sufficiently large window, albeit with a performance hit.

To illustrate, calling the following URI in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/calendarview?startdatetime=2009-01-01&enddatetime=2019-12-31&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com) returns a full decade (2009-2019) of events:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2009-01-01&enddatetime=2019-12-31
```

It's worth noting that this took 6,436 milliseconds to return a result and the data only contains a small number of events. When I ran this same query against *my* calendar it took 13,883 milliseconds. So purely from a performance perspective, I wouldn't recommend regularly querying for more than 12 months at a time (i.e. `startdatetime=2018-01-01&enddatetime=2018-12-31` took 2795ms).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. The thing is that it is just for synchronization so a couple seconds is not a problem. But almost 14 seconds is too much indeed. I will go with the calendarview with a lower range.

Comment: If you're syncing, you should [use Deltas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) instead of pulling the entire thing each time. The first pass gives you everything but subsequent calls will only return changes to the calendar. This will save you a _lot_ of processing.

Comment: Yes that's what I intended that's why I didn't care much about the first synchronization time. However if I use deltas, will the start and end date still apply on the delta? Even though I don't pass the parameters to it?

Comment: It will maintain the date window, yes. This is why I suggested using a full year. When I've done this in the past, I've maintained two tokens. One for the current year, another for the subsequent year. On 12/31 I make the "subsequent" token the "current" token and pull a fresh delta for the next year.